# Where do I pick up an Enterprise rental car at EWR?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, ewr

I booked a car from Enterprise at EWR on Orbitz. I'm coming from the city, not from a flight, so I'm just using EWR to rent a car as it's significantly cheaper than renting in Manhattan, and it's in the direction I'm heading anyways, so I'll avoid a bridge/tunnel toll (albeit adding an NJT fare) and (hopefully) some traffic as well.

In the Orbitz listing page, it claimed that it was at a terminal, with a shuttle to the car itself. However, after booking, I received this message:

> When you arrive
>
> FOLLOW THE CAR RENTAL RETURN SIGNS TO THE ENTERPRISE RETURN LANE. PLACE THE KEYS IN THE RETURN BOX LOCATED JUST IN FRONT OF THE RENTAL CAR RETURN BOOTH.
> PLEASE PROCEED TO THE SECOND LEVEL OF THE AIRPORT AND RIDE THE AIR TRAIN TO STATION P3. TAKE THE ESCALATOR DOWNSTAIRS, TURN LEFT AND WALK THROUGH THE SLIDING DOORS TO OUR COUNTER. SELF-SERVICE KIOSKS AT THIS LOCATION CAN MAKE YOUR RENTAL TRANSACTION QUICK AND EASY.

This sounds like it's for returning the car, but it sounds like I should go to `P3` to find the Enterprise counter. However, the [AirTrain](http://www.njtransit.com/pdf/AirTrain-Map.pdf) map claims that Enterprise is at `P1`. So there are three possible locations:

- A terminal (any of them?)
- P1
- P3

Which am I actually supposed to go to?

Comment: If you search the Enterprise website it actually gives you the address, and through Google maps the location, of the Enterprise car rental at EWB. It's marked on Google maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The date on that Air Train map is July 28, 2008.  Also, the map is hosted on the site of NJ Transit, which doesn't run the Air Train.  The Air Train is a service of the Port Authority of New York and New Jersey.  See http://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-car-rental.html.

That site indicates that Enterprise is at P3, as do Google Maps and the Enterprise site itself.

The Orbitz text about the car being at a terminal with a shuttle is probably a standard text that is used at many airports and that doesn't take into account the difference between a van shuttle and the Air Train.

Of the five sources of information, the most reliable and up to date are the Port Authority site, Google Maps, and the Enterprise site.  Since they also agree with each other, it is safe to conclude that the Enterprise office is at Air Train station P3.

Comment: Having picked up the car 2 weeks ago from Enterprise at Newark.  I can confirm that it is at an Airtran P3 stop.  There are no in terminal car rental counters at Newark save for the phone booth from which you can rent a car if needed.  And the airtran map hasn't changed.

Comment: @Karlson I don't know why you say the airtrain map hasn't changed; the PANYNJ map is definitely newer than the one on the NJT site, and doesn't show Enterprise at P1: http://www.panynj.gov/airports/pdf/ewr-airtrain-brochure-english.pdf